# how to select function template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void fun(T  t)
{
    cout << "match T" << endl;
}

template<>
void fun(int const& t)
{
    cout <<"match int const & "<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const int x =12;
    const int& y =x;
    fun(x); //why not the second?
    fun(y); //why?
    fun(4);//why?

    return 0;
}

Output:

match T
match T
match T
```

we know that after function template overload resolve, compiler should select best match specialization from selected base function template?
what is the rule?

Comment: That's why you [overload rather than specialize function templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm).

Comment: @Quentin Unfortunately we can't close as a dupe of the link. Surely there must be an SO Q about that.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that's fine, I just don't have the time to write a full answer, and link-only answers are prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different templates!

What you want to do is

```
template<>
void fun<const int>(const int& t)
{
    cout << "match const int & " << endl;
}
```

Notice two things:

1. for the specialized function, the <> operator specifying the specialization comes after the function name
2. `const type` and `type const` are two different things, in principle; this gets hairy when `type` is a pointer (is it a constant pointer or a pointer to a constant?)!

Also, as the comments already point out, there's no good reason to use templates here. A simple overloaded function will do.

Comment: If you compile and run that, you'll notice that it doesn't change the behavior. Also, `const type` and `type const` are exactly the same thing. That `const` has to appear on the right side of the `*` to declare a pointer constant does not change this; `const foo *const` is exactly the same as `foo const *const`.

Comment: yes, that's why I wrote *in principle*; `const foo *const` == `foo const *const`, but `const *foo` is not the same as `foo *const`.

Answer (score 0):

You specialize the template for the case when `T` = `int const&`. However, according to the rules of template argument deduction, `int` is deduced (and the primary template is instantiated).

Instead, overload by writing a non-template function taking `int const&`. (Direct reference bindings have Exact Match Rank, so that function should be selected.)

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have attempted to write an answer from my prehistoric Blackberry... No standard quotes or examples included. :/